# How to render some html using django form

Tags: html, django, forms

Could I render some html using django forms/widgets ?

I have a following form :

```
from django import forms
from models import TextNote
class AddNoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    note_value=forms.CharField(min_length=10,
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 60, 'rows': 20}))
class Meta:
    model = TextNote
    fields = ['note_name','note_value','note_image',]

class Media:
    js = ('/media/js/counter.js',)
```

I can't change html-template, so I need to find any possibility to add some html-code to templete via form render. How could I do this?
Thanks for advise.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what HTML you wish to add ? Depending of your answer you'd better add in in the widget python code, in the form python code, or in the form html template code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another JS in media (or edit the existing one if possible). Manipulate the HTML through the added JS. [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) or similar such library can be used to easily do this.

```
class Media:
    js = ('/media/js/counter.js', '/media/js/updateform.js')
```

Add your code in `/media/js/updateform.js` to manipulate the form.

Comment: Also I need to add {{ form.media }} to admin page. I try to override this admin site page.. But I can't find it in django.contrib.admin.templates. Maybe exsists more right way to do this without admin page overriding?